# 503 error: Google app engine - but the api call is not called from my code...?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am working on an android app with a simple google app engine backend.

I am running into difficulty with actually using my backend!  I am able to successfully post new data to my backend, and have it saved in google app engine, but when I try to read data it fails.

It is failing entirely.  When I call the service I get a "503" error. Basically meaning that the function Im calling doesn't exist (at least thats what I think it means).

On further inspection, I noticed that when I look at the server's log file, it is reporting that it is looking for a method called "liststuff".

I don't have a method called "liststuff".  Nor does the word "liststuff" appear anywhere in my code (anymore).  I have updated the code, but I do not see the changes on the server.  I use maven, and specifically I am calling:
1. mvn clean install
2. mvn appengine:update

with success.  But despite this success I am seeing this error messege listing "listStuff" as the method (or remote api method) that is causing the issue.  THIS METHOD DOESN"T EXIST!

What do I need to do to get this to work properly..?

```
/_ah/spi/com.myCompany.myModule.endpoints.GetPostsEndpoint.listStuff
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:147)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
```

Comment: Please search your web.xml for listStuff,

Comment: the fact you say it's not there "anymore" makes me think you maybe never updated the "new" module and you're still hitting the old one?maybe your read function isn't properly updated and causes this discrepancy? I would try to upload to a completely brand new project, just to see